# Push notifications not receiving on device

Tags: iphone, ipad, push-notification, sandbox

I am using APNS service in my universal app (iPhone/iPad) and i am not geting notifications on device. Previously i was getting notifications perfectly but now a days with the same code at server side and client, it is not working. 
On server side notification status is delivered but i am not receiving it on my device.

I have checked most of the questions on stackoverflow but i was unable to find my question. one guy said that in development environment it may have delays, but my problem is that i am not receiving notifications at all.

Note: i am using sandbox environment not production.

Comment: Might want to check if you certificate for the sandbox environment is still valid. It has a limited life span

Comment: Thanx frank for reply but i checked my certificate and its expiry is in 25aug2012 well i created new certificate and everything but still in vain

Comment: That long? Normally the sandbox (development) certificate is only valid for 3 months

Comment: i have already configured my app id for development and it was working almost 15 days ago. but now it is not working without any change

Comment: thanx to all, my problem is solved. But still i dont know what was the problem lolzz, well i just make new certificate and everything else and it start working, my certificate was not expired but i created new certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I just revoke my certificates
- Uploaded new certificates deleted all provision from my organizer
  and then created new provisions and installed them on my system.
  At the same time I got my APNS working.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you haven't found a solution yet, one additional thing you could check is if your device's date and time is properly set (*in the OS*).  If your iPod, iPhone or iPad isn't set to the **current date**, we found that notifications are ignored silently.  Of course, there are many other possible explanations as to why your service stopped working, but this is a simple thing to check when everything else appears to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the things you can check

1. Check the entitlements while codesigning the app. (They can be seen in Xcode build log).
2. Check whether notifications are on for the device in the settings menu.
3. If you are using corporate network on the iOS device, the push notifications might be blocked. Try using a different network.
4. After launching the app, check the organizer for any logs with the reason why push notifications can not be enabled.

I hope some of this helps you out.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html talks in details about various issues faced in registering and receiving push notifications.